# Detect camera collision in OpenGL without using bounding box

Tags: opengl, c++, visual-studio

Is there any way to detect collisions in `OpenGL` without using any kind of bounding box?

I have created a maze/labyrinth and I want to move the camera/player inside the maze, such that the movement of camera is restricted by the walls of the maze.

Comment: You might be able too.. But why don't you want a bounding box? Seems like the easiest solution by far to me.

Comment: Professor has given me an assignment, where I have to move the camera/player using the arrow keys and mouse, without using a bounding box

Comment: When i asked him more about it, he replied this>> It is not a replacement of bounding boxes. You do not do collission detection. This slide is an alternative to that. Instead of detecting collisions, you have a map that define which movements are valid. Check this tutorial for further details.

http://archive.gamedev.net/archive/reference/programming/features/arttilebase/

Answer (score 3):

OpenGL is a graphics API, whose sole purpose is shoving triangles to your screen. It does not do collision detection, at all.

If your maze has orthogonal walls, an axis-aligned bounding box is definitely the easiest collision detection you can code.